# MOSFETs in series length

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, cmos

[image]

[Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits by Razavi]

Can someone explain to me why in Fig 3.71, if M1 and M2 have the same dimensions, that it is equivalent to a single transistor with 2L and same W? I don't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is the layout of a single nmos transistor it consists of a polysilicon gate with a piece of n type material on either side. It has a width W and length L. These terms are often confused, L refers to the length of the channel from one side to the other and W is the width of the channel from the top to the bottom of the device as drawn.

[image: Single Transistor]

Now lets wire two of these in series. The interconnect is represented by simple lines in reality it typically involves metal layers and vias.

[image: Two in series]

We can move these together and combine the n regions in the middle into one region. This is very commonly done in silicon design.

[image: Two in series combined]

As the gates are common we can go ahead and move the two gate regions together forming a single transistor of length 2l and width w.

[image: Final Result 2l]

As a first order approximation comparing the properties of transistors in one technology, the properties of the transistor are dependant only on W L and the voltage gradient across the gate. Looking at the steps above these are maintained throughout the merger process.

Comment: Fantastic answer and step by step illustration!!

Comment: The question refers to the “poor man’s cascode” where the top transistor would have a lower threshold voltage to keep the bottom transistor saturated—not sure you can combine them in that case. Also, considering second order  effects and identical transistors, I think a single long fet would have less overlap capacitance and junction leakage.